# How to get long long mask by number?

Tags: c++

Say to list all masks we use:

```
for (unsigned long long mask = 1; mask != 0; mask <<= 1) {

}
```

but here we move using operator `<<=` one by one our mask value, how to step over to mask number `20` or `55`?

Comment: Pretty simple `mask = 1LL << 20;` or `mask = 1LL << 55;`

Answer (score 2):

Just set `mask` to the value you want to set it to.

```
mask = 1LL << 20;
```