# How to get a number from unsigned long long mask?

Tags: c++

I wonder how to reverse something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037785/how-to-get-long-long-mask-by-number). So having a `mask` where `auto mask = 1ULL << 20;` how to get `20` out from mask?

Comment: Log to the base 2(number)!

Comment: Do you know there's exactly one bit set?

Comment: [Bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogLookup) is your friend.

Answer (score 11):

### Loop-free

Many years ago when I was writing a bit-wise arithmetic for a chess engine, I found a fast implementation which is useful for your requirement, it's loop-free. This method will return the position of the first `1`-bit from right-to-left (Least Significant Bit):

```
inline unsigned int lsb(unsigned long long value)
{
    if (!value)
        return -1;

    value &= -value;
    unsigned int lsb = (unsigned) value | (unsigned) (value >> 32);
    return (((((((((((unsigned) (value >> 32) != 0) << 1)
            + ((lsb & 0xffff0000) != 0)) << 1)
            + ((lsb & 0xff00ff00) != 0)) << 1)
            + ((lsb & 0xf0f0f0f0) != 0)) << 1)
            + ((lsb & 0xcccccccc) != 0)) << 1)
            + ((lsb & 0xaaaaaaaa) != 0);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long x = 1ULL<<20;
    cout << lsb(x) << endl;
}
```

Output

```
20
```

I think, I had found it [here](http://www.stmintz.com/ccc/index.php?id=236134).

Comment: yes i asked it because you had written just int:-) now +1.inline is also good to keep i guess.

Comment: And this is one unreadable mess. I'm certain there's something clever in there, but it needs comments, lots of comments! Also, it would be interesting to benchmark this compared to the simple loop.

Comment: I've did a simple benchmark and compared three solutions from here ([lsb](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16140560/952747), [loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16140523/952747) and [look-up](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16141023/952747)). You can see the test [here](http://ideone.com/LA0nWf). This code is x3.4 times better than a simple loop, and x1.6 times better than look-up. Also, I agree about comments on the code.

Comment: Comments needed? Really? After the `(lsb & 0xFFFF0000) != 0` I understood the algorithm. BTW the `value &= -value` is not needed if the input is a power of 2, nor is the `value==0` check.

Comment: @MSalters Code that is not immediately obvious should always have comments. This code is not obvious. Yes, you will understand it after a while, but you should understand it immediately. I had to test it with a number first to understand the `&= -value` and `lsb =`. Naming variables `value` is always a bit problematic.

Comment: If your platform supports CountLeadingZeros (clz), then it becomes very quick indeed to perform a log base 2 calc...

Answer (score 6):

Using log:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
int main() {
    auto mask = 1ULL << 20; 
    std::cout << log2(mask) << std::endl;
    // edit out: std::cout << log(mask) / log(2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

or loop and shift:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    auto mask = 1ULL << 20; 
    for (unsigned int c = 0; c < sizeof(mask) * 8 && mask; c++) {
        mask >>= 1;
        if (mask == 0)
            std::cout << c << std::endl;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 2 log calls will be a bit slow in comparison to a loop, I'd have thought

Comment: Surely you could have used the `log2` function?

Answer (score 5):

If it's a 64-bit mask, you can compute it modulo 67 and do a table lookup.

To wit:

```
static int table[67] = {
  -1, 0, 1,39, 2,15,40,23, 3,12,
  16,59,41,19,24,54, 4,-1,13,10,
  17,62,60,28,42,30,20,51,25,44,
  55,47, 5,32,-1,38,14,22,11,58,
  18,53,63, 9,61,27,29,50,43,46,
  31,37,21,57,52, 8,26,49,45,36,
  56, 7,48,35, 6,34,33};

int unmask(unsigned long long ull) {
 return table[ull % 67];
}
```

Comment: To see the benchmark, see my answer. I compared this and my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop will be quite okay:

```
for (int bit = 0; bit < sizeof(mask) * 8; bit++)
{
    if ((1ULL << bit) & mask)
        std::cout << "Bit " << bit << " is set in the mask\n";
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `sizeof(mask) * 8`.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: iterate

```
while (mask && !(mask & 1)) { mask>>=1; count++; }
```

Option 2: iterate multiple bits at a time:

```
unsigned long long a=0xFFFFFFFFULL; int b=32;
while (mask>1) {
    if (!(mask & a)) { count+=b; mask>>=b; }
    b>>=1; mask>>=b;
}
```

Option 3: Convert the mask to double or float and extract the exponent.

```
union { 
     struct {
        int mantissa:23;
        int exp:7;
        int sign:1;
     } s;
     float f;
} u = { (float) mask };

return u.s.exp + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//first if you want to make sure only 1 bit is "on" you can do that:
if ((mask & mask-1) != 0)
{
    //you have more than 1 bit "on", deal with it...
}

//finding which bit is "on" can be achieve in a loop
int count 0;
while (mask > 1)
{
    mask>>=1;
    count++;
}

//At this point count will have the required value (20 in your example)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a TMP solution:

```
#include <iostream>

template < unsigned long long MASK >
struct MaskIndex
{
    enum { i = MaskIndex < MASK / 2 >::i + 1 };
};

template <>
struct MaskIndex < 1 >
{
    enum { i = 0 };
};

int main()
{
    const unsigned long long mask = 1ULL << 20;
    std::cout << MaskIndex < mask >::i << std::endl;
    return ( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Of course, with this code, you can't check if the input actually has only 1 bit set.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this..

```
if((1ULL<<20)&mask) {
        cout << "20th bit is set";
}
```